# Eclipse Indigo for OS X Mavericks launched with Java SE 7

Tags: java-7, osx-mavericks, eclipse-indigo

I wanted to install eclipe Indigo SR2 on Mac OSX Mavericks and I got this message when I launched **./eclipse** in Terminal :

> Alert : Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine

And that in the Terminal:

```
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
```

I have that on my System :

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Are you able to launch Eclipse from Finder?

Comment: Any problem, it works with Finder too.

Answer (score 7):

What I have done:

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/
sudo mkdir bundle
cd bundle
sudo mkdir Libraries
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib libserver.dylib
```

It works!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. This is a useful fix, however unfortunate that it must be fixed at all.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done:

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/Home/bundle bundle
```

It works!